# How do I grab the value of a date input?

Tags: javascript, html, date, input-field

So basically I want the price of "renting a boat" to change when a specific requirement is met. If the user selects a date that is on a weekday it will grab the value from the input field and the price will be 10$ per hour. If its a Saturday the price will be 15$ per hour, and if its a Sunday the price will be 20$ per hour. The user can rent it up to 10 hours and they will get a total price at the bottom.

All I have at the moment is the HTML code for the input fields, and I don't even know how to begin the JavaScript part. So if anyone can teach how to start that would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div id="main">
  
    <label for="which_date">Which date do you want to rent?</label>
    <input type="date" id="which_date_input" min="2022-05-02">
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  
    <label for="total_hours">How many hours do you want to rent? (Max 10 hours)</label>
    <input type="number" id="total_hours_input" placeholder="0" min="1" max="10">

    <p id="result"></p>
```

I'm sorry if the explanation of what I want is hard to understand, I'm a beginner when it comes to JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: You can add an onchange function on the date input and use Javascript Date class's getDay() method to check if it's a weekday or a weekend whenever the date input changes.

Comment: @DavePritlove Tritonex is asking a specific valid SO question. 
Even with some understanding of the DOM it's still hard to know where to start sometimes. Let's just be supportive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this...

```js
function getPrice() {

  const whichDate = new Date(document.getElementById("which_date_input").value);

  const totalHours = document.getElementById("total_hours_input").value;

  let perHour = 10;

  if (whichDate.getDay() === 6) {
    perHour = 15;
  }

  if (whichDate.getDay() === 0) {
    perHour = 20;
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerText = "Total price: $" + totalHours * perHour;

}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <label for="which_date">Which date do you want the ticket for?</label><br>
  <input type="date" id="which_date_input" min="2022-05-02"><br>

  <label for="total_hours">How many hours do you want to rent? (Max 10 hours)</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="total_hours_input" placeholder="0" min="1" max="10">
  <button id="submit" onclick="getPrice()">Submit</button><br>

  <p id="result"></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give somewhat of a good indication of what you're trying to do.
You can use the `input` event along with `target.value` to get the value.
I'm getting `value` by destructuring:  `const {value} = target` it's similar to `target.value`.

If you don't want to work with real-time results you can use something like `submitButton.addEventListener('submit', ...` instead where you set the submitButton via `querySelector`.  but you will still need to read the same `target.value` from the "hours" input element if you decide to go that way.

```
// Do something with the results
const someAction = (amount) => {
  console.log(`The amount is: £${amount}`)
}

// Get the input element
const totalHoursInput = document.querySelector("#total_hours_input")

// Listen to the input event
totalHoursInput.addEventListener("input", ({
  target
}) => {

  // Get the day name
  const day = new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', {
    weekday: 'long'
  }).toLocaleLowerCase()

  const { value } = target // The input value 

  // Determine the correct rate
  let rate = 10  // Weekday default 
  if (day === "saturday") {
    rate = 15
  } else if (day === "sunday") {
    rate = 20
  }

  // do something with the rate x value
  someAction(rate * value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label for="which_date">Which date do you want the ticket for?</label>
<input type="date" id="which_date_input" value="" min="2022-05-02">

<button id="submit" onclick="getDate()">Submit</button>



<p id="result"></p>

<script>
function getDate() {
  var x = document.getElementById("which_date_input").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

now use what condition you want to apply on var X. the pick up date will store in x you can use for your conditions.